# How to select iterator type using auto variable?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++11, auto

I have a std::unordered_map

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> myMap;
```

I want to get a const iterator using find. In c++03 I would do

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator = myMap.find("SomeValue");
```

In c++11 I would want to use auto instead to cut down on the templates

```
auto = myMap.find("SomeValue");
```

Will this be a const_iterator or iterator? How does the compiler decide which to use? Is there a way I can force it to choose const?

Comment: Perhaps the compiler is doing function-wide type inference... But why does the constness of the iterator matters to you?

Comment: Unless my understanding of overloading is wrong (or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find is wrong), `nonConstMap.find` always returns an `iterator`. The return type and what you do with the result (e.g. pass it to a `const_iterator` constructor) does not affect which overload is chosen. That is, it only returns a `const_iterator` if you call `constMap.find`.

Answer (score 8):

It will use non-const iterators if `myMap` is a non-const expression. You could therefore say

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename Vc> struct apply_vc;
template<typename T, typename U> struct apply_vc<T, U&> {
  typedef T &type;
};
template<typename T, typename U> struct apply_vc<T, U&&> {
  typedef T &&type;
};

template<typename T> 
typename apply_vc<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type const, T&&>::type
const_(T &&t) {
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

And then

```
auto it = const_(myMap).find("SomeValue");
```

Comment: Why not just `template<typename T> const T& const_(T& t) { return t; }` ?

Comment: That will not work with nonconst rvalues and will transform const rvalues to lvalues. not good.

Comment: I hadn't considered the latter (why make something `const` which is already `const`?), but you'd trivially solve that with an overload anyway. The rvalue case is good, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around `apply_vc`. I see _what_ it does, but not why it's necessary.

Comment: It keeps rvalues as rvalues and lvalues as lvalues so that ref qualifier overloading of memberfunctions still work.

Comment: c++17 has added std::as_const to the header <utility> [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const)