# How do I get a const_iterator using auto?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

First question: is it possible to "force" a `const_iterator` using auto?
For example:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, int> usa;
//...init usa
auto city_it = usa.find("New York");
```

I just want to query, instead of changing anything pointed by `city_it`, so I'd like to have `city_it` to be `map<int>::const_iterator`. But by using auto, `city_it` is the same to the return type of `map::find()`, which is `map<int>::iterator`. Any suggestion?

Comment: You want a variable of a specific type without specifying the type?  Sorry, it can't be done easily in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select iterator type using auto variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453383/how-to-select-iterator-type-using-auto-variable)

Comment: Maybe `static_cast<map<int> const &>(usa).find("New York")`?

Comment: `map<int>` is an error (if you mean `std::map`). You must specify at least two template parameters; the key type and the value type.

Comment: "const auto" is OK in many situations so it's not that absurd

Comment: Even though `const auto` may be ok depending on your needs it should have been possible to do `auto city_it = usa.cfind("New York")` to be consistent with `cbegin()`, `cend()` etc... but it was probably forgotten. Your question will hopefully be a reminder and one day we will have `std::cfind`.

Comment: @QuentinUK How "const auto" is OK if you *can* still modify the object(pointed to by the iterator)? "const auto" only makes the iterator itself const, doesn't it?

Comment: @PatrickFromberg Do you mean `std::map<...>::cfind`? Because we don't need `std::cfind` as we can use `cbegin()` and `cend()`.

Comment: @starriet You can do `auto const & cs = example;
    auto cit = cs.find(2);` then cit is a const_iterator and the thing being pointed to can't be changed.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sorry, but I just think the best suggestion is **not** using `auto` at all, since you want to perform a (implicitly valid) **type conversion**. `auto` is meant for deducing the *exact type*, which is not what you want here.

Just write it this way:

```
std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator city_it = usa.find("New York");
```

As correctly pointed out by MooingDuck, using type aliases can improve the readability and maintainability of your code:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, int> my_map;
my_map::const_iterator city_it = usa.find("New York");
```

Comment: Or, if for any obscure reason someone hates typedefs, there is still `decltype(usa.cbegin()) it = ...` ;)

Comment: @us2012: Yes, that would work, but I wouldn't be able to decide between  `cbegin()` and `cend()` :-D Just kidding

Answer (score 29):

Since C++17 you can use [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) like this:

```
#include <utility>

// ...

auto city_it = std::as_const(usa).find("New York");
```

Answer (score 13):

A clean solution is to work with a *const* reference to the otherwise modifiable map:

```
const auto &const_usa = usa;
auto city_it = const_usa.find("New York");
```

This will make sure you can't modify `const_usa`, and will use const iterators.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't a drastically different take on conversion to `const` in comparision to @Jollymorphic's answer, but I think that having a utility one-liner function like this is handy:

```
template<class T> T const& constant(T& v){ return v; }
```

Which makes the conversion much more appealing to the eye:

```
auto it = constant(usa).find("New York");
// other solutions for direct lengths comparision
std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator city_it = usa.find("New York");
auto city_it = const_cast<const std::map<std::string, int>&>(usa).find("New York");
```

Well, I'd say, bigger isn't always better. You can of course choose the name of the function according to your preferences - `as_const` or just `const_` are possible alternatives.

Comment: I used `make_const` on the occasion I used this idea.

Comment: @GMan: `make_x` implies, to me atleast, the *creation* of something *new* that wasn't there before. That's why I opted for `as_const`, which changes the *view* on the object.

Comment: c++17 has added std::as_const to the header <utility> [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const)

Answer (score 6):

Another variation using auto (keeping both a mutable usa and a const usa):

```
map<std::string, int> usa;
//...init usa
const auto &const_usa = usa;
auto city_it = const_usa.find("New York");
```

If you don't need the map to be mutable at all after init there are some other options.

you can define usa as const and init it with a function call:

```
const map<std::string, int> usa = init_usa();
auto city_it = usa.find("New York");
```

or using a lambda to init a const map:

```
const auto usa = [&]()->const map<std::string, int> 
   {
   map<std::string, int> usa;
   //...init usa
   return usa;
   }();
auto city_it = usa.find("New York");
```

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, you can do this:

```cpp
decltype(usa)::const_iterator city_it = usa.find("New York");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in a position to test this right now, but I think it'll do the trick:

```
auto city_it = const_cast< const map<int> & >(usa).find("New York");
```

Comment: Hmm, but what makes this solution better than simply specifiying `map<int>::const_iterator` as the type? It's not shorter or more readable in any way.

Comment: @us2012: technically, OP didn't request shorter or more readable, he requested a `const_iterator` using `auto`, which is exactly what this allows. :P

Answer (score -3):

You can use auto to "track" a type or "deduce" a type: 

`// deduce
auto city_it = usa.find("New York");`

`// track 
auto city_it = std::map<int>::const_iterator( usa.find("New York"));`

Also, watch is modern c++ style talks by Herb Sutter, which covers most of these type deductions guidance. 
https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64

Comment: `auto city_it = {std::map<int>::const_iterator} usa.find("New York");` is a syntax error. Can you rephrase your answer and explain a bit more about what you are trying to say?

Comment: It is still an error, `map<int>` is not a type. And you do not explain what the difference between "deduce" and "track" is.