# How get non-const iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

```
std::map<char,int> dict;
...
auto pmax = dict.begin(); // here i get const iterator
```

Can I "explicitly indicate" that the value obtained is a non-constant type?

Comment: If you like to have it short, use a `typedef` to create an alias for an iterator like `typedef std::map<char, int>::iterator MCIIT;`, but refrain from using to much `auto`

Comment: Unless `dict` is const, you're not getting a const iterator with that code.  It's just that the `pmax->first` is const, because that's the way maps work.  They maintain their order by the key, and so that key must not be modifiable.

Comment: ahah here’s the nice example of how bad is programing teachers: they tell you things without explainations.

Comment: You should post a complete example, because there are several open questions about your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select iterator type using auto variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453383/how-to-select-iterator-type-using-auto-variable)

Comment: What do you actually want to do? A [short](http://ideone.com/GmtpDq) experiment shows, you can modify the `pmax->second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your [code](http://codepad.org/qcFBNZK8), you are basically implementing `std::max_element`. So you could rewrite your last output line to:

```
    std::cout << std::max_element(begin(dict), end(dict),
        [](decltype(*begin(dict)) a, decltype(*begin(dict)) b) {
            return a.second < b.second;
        })->first << std::endl;
```

Admittedly, the `decltype(*begin(dict))` is ugly, which hopefully will be remedied by generic lambdas in C++1y.

The point is, that regardless of whether you have a `map::iterator` or `map::const_iterator` when you dereference it, the result will be a `std::pair` with a `const key_type` as first argument. So, even if you have two `iterator`s `it1, it2` to mutable data (e.g., acquired via `map::begin()`), you can not re-assign the complete `pair` that is referenced by those iterators. Thus, `*it1 = *it2` won't work, because you are trying to overwrite the `mapped_type` **and** the `const key_type`.

Answer (score 3):

If your `dict` is not `const`, [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin) will return a `std::map<char,int>::iterator`. Now, the key is `const`, but the value is not.

`auto` should give you a `std::map<char,int>::iterator`; do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @ObiSan: Return value of what?  I have MSVC 2012 and its behavior regarding the return value of `std::map<char,int>::begin` is perfectly normal.  It returns `std::map<char,int>::iterator`, who's value_type is `std::pair<const char,int>`. You'll need to present a complete example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @ObiSan That's useless; it's ignoring `auto`.

Comment: @ObiSan: A description about the problem you are having with the code would also be nice.  I presume your issue is that, when you uncomment the commented code, `*pmax = p;` does not compile.  That problem is explained in this answer, and in my comment below your question.  The iterator is not const.  The key value is const.  This is necessary in order for a map to maintain its order.  If the iterator was const, the mapped value would also be const.  Try `pmax->second = 10;`, and you will see that it is not.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for debug version. If i uncomment the commented code, i get error in line '*pmax = p' - like "l-value is pointing to an object-constant (const)".