# How does one achieve const_auto, since C++11 lacks it?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, const-iterator

The `auto` type of C++11 is handy, so now one wants a `const_auto` type, too.  For example, supposing `std::list<T> a;`, if

```
auto p = a.begin();
```

has the type `std::list<T>::iterator`, then one wishes that

```
const_auto p = a.begin();
```

had the type `std::list<T>::const_iterator`.  Unfortunately, C++11 does not seem to have heard of `const_auto`.  Therefore, how can one achieve the desired effect with good style, please?

(For information, [a related question is asked and answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15758629/1275653))

Comment: Reason why is because auto get the type being assigned to it.  const_auto wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: I've used `auto r = some_cv_overloaded_operation(as_const(a));` once or twice, I find it useful when the need arises (writing `as_const` left as an exercise).

Comment: @Adrian:  Of course you are right.  Indeed, I understood that when I asked the question.  Thank you for explicitly pointing it out, though.

Comment: @LucDanton:  Your comment makes a good answer.  If you added it as an answer, then naturally I would upvote it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++11 does allow you to write

```
const auto p = a.begin();
```

However, this doesn't do what you want. This makes a regular iterator to non-constant data whose value cannot be changed.

The type of the right-hand side `a.begin()`is determined by the type of `a`, and not by anything on the left-hand side.  If a is non-const, then the non-const version of `a.begin()` will be called.  So, you could cast `a` to a const& and then use it, or you could make a constant reference to a and use that:

```
const auto& b = a;
auto p = b.begin();
```

However, a simpler approach would be to use the newly introduced .cbegin() and .cend():

```
auto p = a.cbegin();
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had not known that.  Can one moreover do likewise with pointers?  That is, if iterators are not involved, but only old-fashioned pointers, then can one somehow use `auto` to get a type like `const T *`?

Comment: Can't do it with pointers since there is no way to determine the **'end'**, but you can do it with arrays.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, this will be possible in C++14: `auto p = cbegin(a);` which does the same but is more generic as it works too if 'a' is a raw array.

Answer (score 3):

I often find it useful to turn instances into the `const` version of their type, but I find using `const_cast` to be vulgar for this purpose (reserve that for *removing* `const`, and now searching for it finds dangerous code), and it is overly verbose (repeating the full type?  Gah!)

Hence this snippet:

```
template<typename T>
T const& as_const( T& t ) { return t; }
```

which you'd then use to solve your problem as follows:

```
auto p = as_const(a).begin();
```

which I believe is pretty self documenting.

Answer (score 2):

There are function templates for STL containers and C arrays in C++11.  See [`std::begin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/begin/) and [`std::end()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/end/).  Unfortunately, there is no equivalent `std::cbegin()` or `std::cend()` for some reason.

You can use these functions to do what you want though:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
T const * cbegin(T(&a)[N])
{
    return &a[0];
}

template<class T, size_t N>
T const * cend(T(&a)[N])
{
    return &a[N];
}

template<class T>
typename T::const_iterator cbegin(T const & container)
{
    return container.cbegin();
}

template<class T>
typename T::const_iterator cend(T const & container)
{
    return container.cend();
}
```

The last two can also be declared as:

```
template<class T>
auto cbegin(T const & container) -> decltype(container.cbegin())
{
    return container.cbegin();
}

template<class T>
auto cend(T const & container) -> decltype(container.cend())
{
    return container.cend();
}
```

From there you can do this:

```
char x[] = "ab";

auto b = cbegin(x);
auto e = cend(x);
```

Comment: I think these are to be in [added](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3688.html#2128) to the standard.  I believe someone hacking libstdc++ is working on it.