# How does the Compiler Know Whether to Call the const Overload?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, overloading, const-iterator

Given `string foo`, when I call:

```
auto bar = foo.begin();
```

There are 2 overloads of [`string::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/begin). One returns an `string::iterator` and the other returns a `string::const_iterator`. How can I know the type of `bar`? Is this just based on whether `foo` is `const` or not?

Comment: "Is this just based on whether foo is const or not?" Yes.

Comment: You can also call `cbegin` if you know for sure you want a `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this just based on whether `foo` is const or not?

**Yes**

`auto` is meant for deducing the *exact type*<sup>*</sup>

---

[How to select iterator type using auto variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453383/how-to-select-iterator-type-using-auto-variable) indirectly agrees with this answer.

*<sub>Taken from: [How do I get a const_iterator using auto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233188/how-do-i-get-a-const-iterator-using-auto)</sub>